# Signal conjugation detected on RF recording samples, why?

Tags: signal-analysis, phase, signal-detection

I collected spread spectrum signals at 400 MHz at low elevation angles using Software Defined Radio complex sampling over the seasons. I noticed that over watery, icy surfaces, the RF samples are conjugated compared with regular open space RF samples, resulting in failed de-spreading. De-spreading works if the signal samples are conjugated. I like to think that this phenomenon can be because the 180 deg. reversal of H vector of the wave front in reflection causing |E x H|atan(-H/E) resulting in a 90 deg. change of phase. This answer just doesn't appear to be convincing. Search the Net, could not find any related report on reflected RF signal has signal sample conjugated. Any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting question. I assume you've ruled out any misconfiguration of your receiver (i.e. if it has configurable spectral inversion, for example).

Comment: I used the same de-spreading routine and the same setup for all other samples successfully. When this RF sample de-spreading failed, that is when I worked out that the failed RF sample has conjugation. All is again well after conjugation of the sample...Yes. I agree that the only possible answer is spectral reversal but just not comfortable blaming this on water and ice...